# Why is there not a solid state fluorescent lamp?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, visible-light, fluorescence

Is it possible to coat a solid piece of metal with fluorescent powder (such as in a tube), and get this to emit light in a strong electric field?

Comment: see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminous_paint

Comment: I should add "static" field to this.

Answer (score 1):

In a fluorescent tube the electric field accelerates electrons in the gas that fills the tube, and those electrons electronically excite or indeed completely ionise the atoms of the gas. Those atoms then emit high energy (blue and ultraviolet light) as they return to the ground state. The job of the fluorescer is to convert this blue/ultraviolet light to white light.

Fluorescers work by absorbing high energy photons, converting some of the original photon energy to heat then re-emitting a lower energy photon. This is how they convert UV to visible light. The process is (unsurprisingly) called [fluorescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorescence). Any single fluorescer works only for a limited range of wavelengths, so in a fluorescent light lots of different fluorescers are combined to produce a mixture of wavelengths that appears white.

The key point here here is that the fluorescer does not interact directly with the electric field. It just converts UV to visible. So when you ask about a solid equivalent of the form you describe it isn't obvious how fluorescence would help you. Instead you would simply use one of the many solid state processes for creating light e.g. [electroluminesce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroluminescence) as used in light emitting diodes. This is the mechanism used in the [electroluminescent wire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroluminescent_wire) that Niels mentions in his answer.

Comment: In a fluorescent tube, the ionised gas emits UV photons which in turn collide with the phosphor, and the phosphor emits visible photons.

What I'd like to know is what analogue to the ionised gas (if any) exists as a solid metal, which will emit enough energy to excite phosphors when placed in a strong, non varying electric field.

Comment: @mike there is no such analogue. The electroluminescent wire that Niels and I have mentioned requires an alternating field and will not work with DC. A light emitting diode works with DC of course.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is called electroluminescent wire and you can buy it by the foot.

Comment: EL wire works on a high-frequency AC electric current in the wire. I am asking if this effect can work in a static field, such as near a tesla coil or high-tension wire.

Comment: Maybe- but efficiencies will be low and will rely upon generation of UV by ionization of nitrogen molecules

Answer (score 0):

In most white LEDs, a gallium nitride GaN solid state diode generates blue light and fluorescent materials then generate the other colors.

https://www.nobelprize.org/uploads/2018/06/popular-physicsprize2014.pdf